# Why md tooltip is not applied to md dummy tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular material.

When I create my own directive and add it to md-tab-label, like

```
<md-tab-label>
<custom-directive>
Label
</cutom-directive>
</md-tab-label>
```

Then the custom directive is applied to some "md-dummy-tab" also.

But if I give mdtooltop to the md-tab-label ,like

```
<md-tab-label>
Label
<md-tooltip>Label</md-tooltip>
</md-tab-label>
```

then there is no md-tooltip applied to "md-dummy-tab" class

I tried searching inside the mdtooltip code, but couldnt get any clue.

https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/tooltip/tooltip.js

How can I do the same for my custom directive , ie custom directive should not apply to md dummy tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`<md-tooltip>`](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/tooltip/tooltip.js) is not appended to the `<md-dummy-tab>` because it doesn't render any HTML code inside the `<md-tab-label>`. Its template is appended to the nearest parent `<md-content>` the moment you trigger the tooltip to show.

```
  scope.$watch('visible', function (isVisible) {
    if (isVisible) showTooltip();
    else hideTooltip();
  });
```

-

```
function showTooltip() {
  // Insert the element before positioning it, so we can get the position
  // and check if we should display it
  tooltipParent.append(element);

  // Check if we should display it or not.
  // This handles hide-* and show-* along with any user defined css
  if ( hasComputedStyleValue('display','none') ) {
    scope.visible = false;
    element.detach();
    return;
  }

  positionTooltip();
  angular.forEach([element, background, content], function (element) {
    $animate.addClass(element, 'md-show');
  });
}
```

-

```
current       = getNearestContentElement(),
tooltipParent = angular.element(current || document.body)
```

-

```
 function getNearestContentElement () {
   var current = element.parent()[0];
   // Look for the nearest parent md-content, stopping at the rootElement.
   while (current && current !== $rootElement[0] && current !== document.body) {
     current = current.parentNode;
   }
   return current;
 }
```

Comment: They watch over the scope visible variable. But how do they know which element is being shown on screen and which element is not? Normally to check if the element is visible on screen, we have to check for its display property or check for offsetHeight. But they are not doing any such thing in their code. So how do they know about visibility of element?